# Create UI from class

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, code-generation

I'am looking for a tool, which can generate a user Interface from a class.
Let me have an example.

This class with some pseudo attributes:

```
class BussinessModel
{
    [UiReadOnly]
    [UiSingleLine]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [UiSingleLine]
    public string Tile { get; set; }

    [UiMultiLine]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

could generate a UI (XAML for the ui) like this:

[image: The generated ui]

**EDIT:**
I fogot to mention about I want "ready to use" bindings which can be used when the given class is the viewmodel (MVVM)

**Is there any tool out there which can do something like this (with a single click)?**

Comment: Check out with [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically need is a dataform.

a search on the "wpf dataform" gives the following link :

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-Rich-Data-Forms-in-Silverlight-3-Introduction.aspx

for the validation attributes, you can start from this one :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335695.aspx

there are also a few commercially available, mainly from Telerik or ComponentOne.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Naked Objects (https://github.com/NakedObjectsGroup/NakedObjectsFramework)

and maybe Executable UML (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_UML)

Naked Objects will dynamically generate Web UI from class definitions at runtime. It also handles persistence via EntityFramework.